# Can you kindly tell the name of this plant?

Tags: identification, outdoor

Can you identify this type of plant? The location is Bridgetown, Barbados.

What is this plant called?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you walk back and take a closeup, especially of the leaves?

Comment: where the picture was taken would help too..

Comment: Could be a gardenia but a better photo is needed , also a location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are pointing at the red flower...well, that's a hibiscus flower.

I can see the  familiar woody stem and leaves of hibiscus along with probably some other plant... check yourself :)

[image]

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibiscus) says:

> Hibiscus[2](https://www.thespruce.com/hibiscus-growing-guide-5192541) is a genus of flowering plants in the mallow family, *Malvaceae*. The genus is quite large, comprising several hundred species that are native to warm temperate, subtropical and tropical regions throughout the world. Member species are renowned for their large, showy flowers and those species are commonly known simply as "hibiscus", or less widely known as **rose mallow**. Other names include **hardy hibiscus**, **rose of sharon**, and **tropical hibiscus.**

If you are interested, you can know more about it from [here](https://www.thespruce.com/hibiscus-growing-guide-5192541)